# Proguard obfuscate Fat jar

Tags: java, proguard

My application jar contains classes from swing-layout.jar which contains free layout manager for java 1.5. During obfuscation process i get a lot of warnings such as

```
[proguard] Note: org.jdesktop.layout.SwingLayoutStyle accesses a field 'INDE
NT' dynamically                                                             
 [proguard]       Maybe this is program field 'org.jdesktop.layout.LayoutStyl
e { int INDENT; }'
```

I would like proguard to leave org.jdesktop classes alone, and get rid of the warnings i tried

```
      -keeppackagenames org.jdesktop.*
```

but it did not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want, I think,

```
-keep org.jdesktop.**
```

Note the two stars. From the [documentation](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/usage.html#filters):

```
*   matches any part of a name not containing the package separator or directory separator.
**  matches any part of a name, possibly containing any number of package separators or directory separators.
```

-keeppackagenames just keeps... package names! You want -keep, which protects the names of things *in* packages.

Comment: i noticed that after asking the question but ** produces the same error messages.

Comment: Oh... You want -keep, not -keeppackagenames. I've edited to reflect this.

Answer (score 10):

old question, but

`-keep org.jdesktop.**`

did not work here with proguard 4.6 - need to add:

`-keep class org.jdesktop.**`

just in case someone stumbles over this question just as I did.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to leave out everything under a specific package, you can do

```
-keep class some.package.** { *; }
```

This will keep all classes in that package, and all fields and methods.